# JIRA - Unable to login when I start an instance of JIRA using atlas-run

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am trying to create an add-on for JIRA.

Steps that I followed:

1. Create a skeleton using "atlas-create-jira-plugin".
2. Atlas-run

When I use `http://XXX:2990/jira`, I am able to view the dashboard but I am not able to login. I get an error message stating "Incorrect User name and password". But I am able to login when I use the same username and password for `http://localhost:8080`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default username and password is: admin/admin

Answer (score 0):

For local development instance, the default username is "admin" and default password is "admin"